# Need to Show Cart button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have developed a music album mobile website, when you hover on the album cover it shows "play" and "cart" buttons. If we click "play" it changes to "Pause", but the cart icon remains same.

Also bottom of the page I have playlist player linked with the album above. We can also play and pause music from the player.

My issue is: when a tone is selected from the player, the album cover should be dark and needs to show the pause and cart icon

```
<div class="col-xs-3">
    <div id="bot8" class="thumb   show-image">
        <img id="img1" src="img/1159347.jpg" class="img-clear">
        <input  id="play_1" data-id="1" class="in-play update" type="image" src="img/play.png" value="1159347.mp3" style="visibility:visible;"/>
        <input id="pause_1" data-id="1" class="in-pause pause update" type="image" src="img/pause.png"  style="display:none;"/>
        <input id="cart1"  class="delete" type="image" src="img/cart.png" value="1159347" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1"  />
    </div>
</div>
```

The code I used as follows

```
/**
 *
 * HTML5 Audio player with playlist
 *
 * Licensed under the MIT license.
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 * 
 * Copyright 2012, Script Tutorials
 * http://www.script-tutorials.com/
 */
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

// inner variables
var song;
var url;
var tracker = $('.tracker');
var volume = $('.volume');

function initAudio(elem) {
    url = elem.attr('audiourl');
    var title = elem.text();
    var cover = elem.attr('cover');
    var artist = elem.attr('artist');

    $('.player .title').text(title);
    $('.player .artist').text(artist);
    $('.player .cover').css('background-image','url(img/' + cover+')');;

    song = new Audio('audio/' + url);

    // timeupdate event listener
    song.addEventListener('timeupdate',function (){
        var curtime = parseInt(song.currentTime, 10);
        tracker.slider('value', curtime);
    });

    $('.playlist li').removeClass('active');
    elem.addClass('active');
}
function playAudio() {
    song.play();
    $("[id^='play_']").attr("style", "visibility:visible");
    $('.play').addClass('hidden');
    $('.pause').addClass('visible');
    $("input[value='"+url+"']").closest('div.thumb').find('input.in-play').hide();
    $("input[value='"+url+"']").closest('div.thumb').find('input.in-pause').show();
}
function stopAudio() {
    song.pause();

    $('.play').removeClass('hidden');
    $('.pause').removeClass('visible');
    $("input[value='"+url+"']").closest('div.thumb').find('input.in-play').show();
    $("input[value='"+url+"']").closest('div.thumb').find('input.in-pause').hide();
}

// play click
$('.play').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    playAudio();
});

// pause click
$('.pause').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    stopAudio();
});

// forward click
$('.fwd').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    stopAudio();

    var next = $('.playlist li.active').next();
    if (next.length == 0) {
        next = $('.playlist li:first-child');
    }
    initAudio(next);
});

// rewind click
$('.rew').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    stopAudio();
    $("[id^='play_']").attr("style", "visibility:visible");
    var prev = $('.playlist li.active').next();
    var url1 = prev.attr('audiourl');
    $("input[value='"+url1+"']").closest('div.thumb').find('input.in-play').show();
    $("input[value='"+url1+"']").closest('div.thumb').find('input.in-pause').hide();
    if (prev.length == 0) {
        prev = $('.playlist li:last-child');
    }
    initAudio(prev);
});

// show playlist
$('.pl').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('.playlist').fadeIn(300);
});

// playlist elements - click
$('.playlist li').click(function () {
    stopAudio();
    initAudio($(this));
});

// initialization - first element in playlist
initAudio($('.playlist li:first-child'));
$("[id^='play_']").click(function(){
  var playid = $(this).attr('id');
  var dataid = $(this).attr('data-id');
  var newurl = $(this).attr('value');
  //$(".player .play").trigger('click');
  //$(".playlist li").trigger('click');
  if (url != newurl) {
    $(".playlist li."+playid).trigger('click');
    playAudio();
  }
  else
    playAudio();
  $('#play_'+dataid).hide();
  $('#pause_'+dataid).show();
   $('#cart_'+dataid).show();
  //$(".player .play").trigger('click');
  //stopAudio();
  //initAudio($(this));

  //initAudio($('.playlist .'+playid));
});
$("[id^='pause_']").click(function(){
  var playid = $(this).attr('id');
  var dataid = $(this).attr('data-id');
  //$(".player .play").trigger('click');
  //$(".playlist li").trigger('click');

  //$(".playlist li."+playid).trigger('click');
  stopAudio();
  $('#play_'+dataid).show();
  $('#pause_'+dataid).hide();
  //$(".player .play").trigger('click');
  //stopAudio();
  //initAudio($(this));

  //initAudio($('.playlist .'+playid));
});
// set volume
song.volume = 0.8;

// initialize the volume slider
volume.slider({
    range: 'min',
    min: 1,
    max: 100,
    value: 80,
    start: function(event,ui) {},
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        song.volume = ui.value / 100;
    },
    stop: function(event,ui) {},
});

// empty tracker slider
tracker.slider({
    range: 'min',
    min: 0, max: 10,
    start: function(event,ui) {},
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        song.currentTime = ui.value;
    },
    stop: function(event,ui) {}
});
});
```

Comment: Can you post some of your HTML as well?

Comment: thanks will post now